# Spring boot 2.0.6 -

Tags: spring, spring-boot, stack-overflow

I am upgrading my app to Spring boot 2.0.6. Maven builds and runs, the unit tests fine. At runtime, while starting up the application container though

I keep seeing this error:-

> 2018-11-21 11:55:30,190 WARN
>  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext -
> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' defined in
> class path resource
>
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor]:
> Factory method 'methodValidationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested
> exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError.

The dependencies in my parent pom are as follows -

```
`<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
 <properties>
    <capitalone.project.version>3.0.1</capitalone.project.version>
    <jackson.version>2.9.7</jackson.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <junit-platform.version>1.1.0</junit-platform.version>
    <sl4j.version>1.7.25</sl4j.version>
    <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Lovelace-RELEASE</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
    <mongodb.version>3.8.2</mongodb.version>
    <pmd.version>3.11.0</pmd.version>
    <jacoco.version>0.8.2</jacoco.version>
    <docker.useConfigFile>false</docker.useConfigFile>
    <mockito.version>2.23.0</mockito.version>
    <docker-maven-plugin.version>1.2.0</docker-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.5.0.1254</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-source-plugin.version>3.0.1</maven-source-plugin.version>
    <maven-javadoc-plugin.version>3.0.1</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>
    <maven-gpg-plugin.version>1.6</maven-gpg-plugin.version>
    <commons-beanutils.version>1.9.3</commons-beanutils.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>6.0.13.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-data-releasetrain.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Finchley.RELEASE</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>`
The pom of my project inherits the above dependencies as it is its parent. Additionally it has the following dependencies defined in it -
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
        <querydsl.version>4.2.1</querydsl.version>
    </properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.capitalone.dashboard</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>${capitalone.project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fakemongo</groupId>
            <artifactId>fongo</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have run out of options now. It looks like its going into some kind of cyclical dependency but not sure what will resolve it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so it might help someone else, I found this post with almost the same stacktrace - https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/issues/50

For me, the problem persisted with Spring boot 2.1.0.RELEASE as well as all the other versions specified in that github forum post.

Eventually, when I ran the application as a normal Spring Boot App via intellij (Yes, Run as Application), it started throwing a different error in the console suggesting that the property names in my properties files were in camel case and they had to be all in lowercase and could have dash(-). After I changed all the property names, it could instantiate the bean alright and the application started up.

Comment: There was a change to spring boot 2, that properties could be input in camel case (for example) but they will always need to be referenced within the app as kebab case. Which might help to explain the issue/search for a root cause.